# How to prevent enabling editing in Protected View in Excel 2013 from altering chart formatting of Excel 2000-2003 and 2007-2010 workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2003

In Excel 2013, when opening and enabling editing from Protected View a macro-enabled Excel workbook downloaded from the internet, with two versions in .xls (Excel 2000-2003) and .xlsm (Excel 2007-2010), charts and diagrams in the workbooks seem to lose their scales, and do not display correctly as they do and should in Protected View. How can the intended look and design of the charts and diagrams be preserved when opening in the files in Excel 2013? See the
[xls and xlsm files in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yhkfhwlmawwwz4f/AADZDp3A_fFg5W_FwRWQEip8a?dl=0). The file is a piece of software that does calculations based on entered data. Some results are plotted on four diagrams, two custom ternary diagrams, and two standard x-y plots, each of which have their own sheet in the workbook. These lose their formatting when enabling editing.